# Python bottle / not working, redirected to router error page

Tags: python, bottle

I'm trying to make a simple web server with bottle.

I've defined '/' as follows:

```
@route('/')
def index():
    output = "{"
    output += "ips: ["

    global servers
    keys = servers.keys()
    for key in keys:
        output += "{' " + key + "' : '" + servers[key] +"'},"
    output += "{'dummy' : 'nodata'}"
    output += "]"
    output += "}"

    return output
```

Which works fine, on the local machine, and also on the local network.
I'm listening on all interfaces by

```
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

However, when I try to access it via my global IP, the router or something redirects me to an endpoint "myip:8080/initfail.html"

Normal apache2 works on port 80, so I know that my computer is available through port forwarding, and if I define the endpoint /initfail.html, I can return a web page with no problem. I guess I could redirect back to / from there but it's as hacky as I can imagine and I can't condone such behaviour.

Is there something extra I need to add to the response like headers or something or anything that is causing the redirect of the router to my computer to fail?

python logs:

```
10.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2017 19:19:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 53
10.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2017 19:19:06] "GET /initfail.html HTTP/1.1" 404 749
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using nginx to reroute to the port from the working port 80